# If select input equals value do this, if it is changed remove those changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select box called "requestHistoryRequestType". I'm trying to write some jQuery so that when the value of that select box is changed I call a function that adds a class and attribute to a field and appends a span to the field that I pass in as a parameter.

The problem is if a user chooses EXPAPP or EXPDEN but then changes their selection to NA it should remove the added stuff from the previous fields and add the same stuff to a different field. Kinda hard to explain, but ask questions away! I'm kinda new to writing complex jQuery like this.

The function that does the adding classes and such:

```
function requiredField(requiredField) {
    $(requiredField).parent().addClass('has-error');
    $(requiredField).attr('data-rule-required', true);
    $("label[for='" + requiredField.replace('#', '') + "']").append("<span style='color:#b94a48;' class='has-error has-tooltip' data-placement='right' title='Required Field'>*</span>");
}
```

The actual on change listener:

```
//Validations for EXPAPP, EXPDEN, and NA
$("#requestHistoryRequestType").on("change", function() {
    if ($("#requestHistoryRequestType").val() === "EXPAPP" || $("#requestHistoryRequestType").val() === "EXPDEN"){
        requiredField("#requestHistoryVerbalDateTime");
        requiredField("#requestHistoryWrittenDateTime");
    } else if ($("#requestHistoryRequestType").val() === "NA") {
        requiredField("#requestHistoryComments");
    }
});
```

Thanks Stack!

Comment: _"writing complex jQuery"_, this is the main problem, it shouldn't be _complex_.

Comment: Well this is complex in the sense that I'm trying to write something that is reusable, hence the function.

Comment: Using reusable functions is the way to go. Note that you can use `this` keyword which refers to the _changed_ element(_ie target of the event_) instead of requerying the DOM, instead of `$("#requestHistoryRequestType").val() === "EXPAPP" || $("#requestHistoryRequestType").val() === "EXPDEN")` you can code: `if ( $.inArray(this.value, ['one', 'two']) > -1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function that would remove the added stuff from all fields and call it before requiredField() calls:

```
function removeRequiredFields()
{
  var $fields = $("#requestHistoryVerbalDateTime, #requestHistoryWrittenDateTime, #requestHistoryComments");
  $fields.parent().removeClass('has-error');
  $fields.attr('data-rule-required', false);
  $fields.each(function() {
    $("label[for='"+$(this).attr('id')+"']").find("[title='Required Field']").remove();
  });
}
```

Or you can pass `$fields` from the event handler to removeRequiredFields() instead of hardcoding it there, for added flexibility.

Comment: Odd, when I use your exact source, I get an error that "Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'attr'"...

Comment: Great. I used this same type of source to iterate through and add the classes. Thanks for the help; now I know how to loop through with .each!

Answer (score 0):

I would just have a separate function for when you select a "NA" rather then trying to build that functionality into the same function.

I'll rewrite your event handler to make it a bit cleaner as well (IMO).

```
//Validations for EXPAPP, EXPDEN, and NA
$("#requestHistoryRequestType").on("change", function() {
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    if (selectedVal  === "EXPAPP" || selectedVal  === "EXPDEN"){
        requiredField("#requestHistoryVerbalDateTime");
        requiredField("#requestHistoryWrittenDateTime");
    } else if (selectedVal  === "NA") {
        requiredField("#requestHistoryComments");
    }
});
```

This way you are not hitting the DOM a potential 3 time to test your conditions every time an event is triggered.  A minor change but probably a useful one as you get into more complex and larger jQuery selectors.

Edit: If you feel you MUST do it in one function then you can call the function with both elements you want to append

```
function requiredField(requiredField1, requiredField2) {
    if (requiredField2 != null){
      $(requiredField1,requiredField1).parent().addClass('has-error');
      $(requiredField1,requiredField1).attr('data-rule-required', true);
      var requiredLabel = "<span style='color:#b94a48;' class='has-error has-tooltip' data-placement='right' title='Required Field'>*</span>"  
      $("label[for='" + requiredField1.replace('#', '') + "']").append(requiredLabel);
      $("label[for='" + requiredField2.replace('#', '') + "']").append(requiredLabel);
    }
    else {
      //remove multiple element classes and add it to the single one representing the "NA"
    }
}
```

This is based on you only ever having one case where you would be passing a single "requiredField" on a case of a "NA"